# Making a qmldir File

Tags: qt, qml

this might seem like the dumbest question ever, but how do you make a qmldir file with Qt Creator? I need to make one so I can use a singleton for my project.

Comment: QtCreator does not have anything special for it, you can make your qmldir with any editor. You can find an example in the following link https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/53288886

Comment: I made with one Terminal and put it in the same directory as Variables, the file in which I'm using a singleton, but the qmldir file isn't included in the project and the project won't run.

Comment: you must add it to the .qrc

Answer (score 4):

Right click in the project pane, the project folder or qrc, depending on your deployment type, `Add New`, `General`, `Empty File`, name it `qmldir` and you are set.

Keep in mind you can also register QML singletons in C++. I prefer this solution wherever possible, as it allows to give the singletons identifiers.